# Diagonalizing a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing diagonalization problems and often end up with the wrong answer because of (I think) one specific thing.

Once I find the eigenvalues, and then the eigenvectors and I put those together to make a matrix Q to diagonalize a matrix by doing (Q^-1)A(Q) = D, does it make a difference in what order I put those eigenvectors into a matrix?

Say I have a matrix 2x2 (1 4 3 2), I get eigenvectors (1 1) and (-4/3 1), the solution I have to this problem puts (-4/3 1) as the first column while I put it as the second and got the wrong answer.

I'm just trying to understand why it matters and what rules do I have to follow to form that Q matrix.

Thank you.

Comment: Well you have to be consistent with the order you put the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix. E.g., if you have three eigenvalues: 1,2,3 and you put them across the diagonal in that order, then the first column of Q will have the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of 1.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Diagonalizing this yields:

$$A = PJP^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -4 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
 \frac{3}{7} & \frac{4}{7} \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, as an experiment, do as @Grid suggests and swap the **eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors**, form the three matrices above and multiply them out. What do you  get?

Now repeat, but swap the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

The eigenvalues **must** track the eigenvectors, but you are free to choose the order.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you put the eigenvectors is unimportant; however, when you are constructing the diagonal matrix it is important that the order of the eigenvalues matches the order chosen for the columns of $Q$.

In short, just be consistent.